# Unexpected output with c++ class

Tags: c++, oop, class

This is my c++ code:

```
class base
{
public:
    int bval;
    base(){ bval=0;}
    void give() { std::cout<<bval<<":"; }
};

void SomeFunc(base *arr,int size)
{
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++,arr++)
        std::cout<<arr->bval;

    std::cout<<"\n";
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++,arr++)
        arr->give();

    std::cout<<"\n";
}

void test_case4()
{
    base BaseArr[5];
    SomeFunc(BaseArr,6);
}
```

I am getting following output for above code:

```
000003379188
0:-1079809464:134515567:134515888:0:-1079809336:
```

Why isn't the second line same as the first and why I am getting a output for the 6th loop in `SomeFunc` when that place hasn't been allocated, I mean there is no code for give() function to execute.

One more thing I know that sizeof operator on a object gives only the size of its data elements not the function that object contain. So if the functions are not located inside the object memory space then where are they stored?

EDIT:

I intentionally incremented the arr for 6th time just to check what happens on executing `give()` function that isn't located on the 6th position.

See the comment to Cem Kalyoncu reply.
Please also answer the first part of my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array, BaseArr has 5 elements, not 6. Its upper bound is 4.

```
base BaseArr[5];
SomeFunc(BaseArr,5); //should fix it.
```

EDIT:
For why you are getting output: in C arrays doesnt have fixed limits, you can easily go out of bounds without getting any errors. Result is generally catastrophic. You will never know what will happen.

EDIT 2:
Today my mind works extra slow, now I understand why you are puzzled. Ok, even if the object pointed by arr is not valid. It is still a memory location. While calling arr->give you are actually calling a function similar to give(arr) . since arr is just a pointer to a memory location call is valid and will not raise any errors, like in c. However, some debuggers are able to notice that you run out of bounds. It is for this purpose vectors are always recommended.

Comment: Cem Kalyoncu: Even if sixth time  counter jump to some location to execute the function code, what make it return from there when there is no return statement like the proper function code and what make it print value to scree when there isn't any code for cout<< statement at that location containig only the garbage location, shouldn't the OS be flagging any error?

Comment: Class function pointers are fixed, unless they are virtual. This means that it will run the same give function as others but with a different memory location. It is no different than having a give(base *) function

Comment: Cem Kalyoncu : Thanks for the reply, my doubt about the give() function is cleared. Could you please answer why two lines on output are different (ignoring the 6th value).

Comment: @gkt.pro: Because you didnt do a reset in between loops. It continues with what ever there in the stack.

Answer (score 4):

You're incrementing the `arr` pointer and going past the size of the original array to which `arr` is pointing to. Also, as Cem points out, the value to the function has to be 5 instead of 6.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you can use a type-safe template.

```
template<size_t size> void SomeFunc(Base (const &arr)[size]) {
    //...
}
```

The size will be automatically deduced by the compiler.

Comment: Size deduction is a fine thing~

Answer (score 0):

***Why the program doesn't crash?***
C/C++ languages do not do any boundary checking with regards to arrays. It depends on the OS   to ensure that you are accessing valid memory.

You are declaring a stack based array(of size 5). Accessing outside the bounds of the array simply accesses another part of the already allocated stack space (most OS's usually reserve a certain portion of memory for stack). Fortunately, you are accessing a out of bound array index(6) which falls within this pre-allocated stack space, and hence it does not crash, but returns the junk data that is present in that specific memory location.

Above it just a logical explanation of what happens but the truth is,

It is ***Undefined Behavior*** to access an array passed its bounds, So it is impossible to define and reason a Undefined Behavior. Period!

***If the functions are not located inside the object memory space then where are they stored?***
The C++ standard doesn't specify where the member functions are to be stored. This behavior is left out as an implementation detail of the compiler. So it might vary from compiler to compiler.

As you rightly said, each object does not have an copy of the member function unlike the member variables. You can consider member functions just like `free functions` but are special in one respect that an implicit `this` pointer is passed to them as an argument.

All compiled code(including member functions) goes into a section of memory as the called `text segment` or the `code segment`. This memory region is separate from `Heap(a.k.a Freestore in C++)`, `Stack` and `Data/BSS` segments which hold dynamically allocated objects, locally declared objects & global or static objects.

Hope that answers your Questions.